# How to change cell value of an html table through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do actually, I have a html table,bellow is the example, It is possible that when you click on a cell content, to pop out a new window which contain the same content of the selected cell and in the new window to have options to Write-Edit-Delete, after you close the window, the modifications are saved in the cell.
 I understood, maybe is possible using java-script

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<style>
body { 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 70% 50%; 
}
</style>



<body >
<form >
<table align="center" border="0">
<tr>
<td> MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td> <td>MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td></tr>

<tr>
<td>MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td> <td><MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this is possible. Did I answer your question, or do you want me to write the code too, because that's not the purpose of StackOverflow. You need to do some work yourself, if you get stuck on some piece of code come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go:

### HTML

```
<form>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="td editable">MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td>
            <td class="td editable">MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td editable">MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td>
            <td class="td editable">MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="editor">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.table {
    border:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.td {
    background:radial-gradient(ellipse 60% 50%, #ccccff, white );
    cursor:pointer;
}
.td:hover {
    background:radial-gradient(ellipse 60% 50%, #8888ff, white );
}

#editor {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding-top:10%;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index:99999;
}

#editor>input {
    width:300px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-width:0;
}

#editor>input::selection { background-color:#00aaff; }
#editor>input::-moz-selection { background-color:#00aaff; }
```

### JavaScript

```
window.editableStart = function($cell) {
    // does not assume it was called in the context of any particular event, but requires one argument specifying the target cell
    var $editor = $('#editor');
    var $input = $editor.children('input');
    var $body = $(document.body);
    $input.val($cell.text());
    $editor.css({'visibility':'visible'});
    $input.select(); // automatically focuses $input
    $editor[0].$cell = $cell; // attach the jQuery object to the editor DOM element as a property for access later
    $body.on('keypress.editable', function(ev) {
        var $input = $('#editor>input');
        if (ev.keyCode === 45)
            $input.focus();
        else
            $input.trigger(ev); // doesn't work if ev.stopPropagation() has been called
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
    $body.on('click.editable', function() { window.editableEnd(false); } );
};

window.editableEnd = function(saveElseDiscard, text ) {
    // does not assume it was called in the context of any particular event, but requires one argument specifying whether to save or discard the edit, and if save, requires a second argument specifying the text
    var $editor = $('#editor');
    if (saveElseDiscard) {
        var $cell = $editor[0].$cell;
        $cell.text(text);
    } // end if
    $editor.css({'visibility':'hidden'});
    var $body = $(document.body);
    $body.off('.editable');
};

$('.editable').on('click', function(ev) {
    window.editableStart($(this));
    ev.stopPropagation();
} );

$('#editor>input').on('click', function(ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); } ); // necessary to stop a click on the input from triggering the click handler on body (which we attach in editableStart())

$('#editor>input').on('keypress', function(ev) {
    //alert(ev.which+' '+ev.keyCode); // hmm, apparently alert() doesn't work from handlers sometimes; see <http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2793749>, but sometimes it does, it's inconsistent; use console.log() instead
    if (ev.which === 13 || ev.keyCode === 27)
        window.editableEnd(ev.which == 13, $(this).val() );
    ev.stopPropagation();
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wv893b0L/2/

Explanation:

- what you probably want is a *modal popup*, which I've coded above. In my experience, the standard way to achieve this is to code the HTML of the popup inside a top-level element (generally a `div`) which is outside most of the rest of the document (still inside `body`, of course), and is CSSed with `position:fixed` to ensure it is fixed within the viewport.
- there are various ways of toggling visibility of the popup, notably including (1) `display:none` vs. `display:block`, (2) `opacity:0` vs. `opacity:1`, and (3) `visibility:hidden` vs. `visibility:visible`. I've used the third in my code.
- to block the rest of the document when the popup is active (if you want to do that, although *not* doing that can introduce complexities regarding interaction between the un-deactivated rest of the document and the popup), what is generally done is that the top-level element wrapping the popup is "maximized" across the whole viewport, which is done with `top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;`, plus `z-index:99999`. Finally, you can achieve a nice "graying" effect with a black (or at least something dark) background with almost-full opacity, e.g. `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);`.
- generally you'll want the actual popup content to be roughly centered on the page, which `text-align:center;` on the wrapping div can accomplish (at least in this case, where we have an `input` inside the div). Also, I've used `padding-top:10%;` on the wrapping div to fix the popup content near the top of the page, although there are tricks to center vertically as well.
- minor point, but I changed your `align="center" border="0"` attributes on the `table` to the equivalent CSS (`border:none; margin:0 auto;`); you should always use CSS in new web code in place of old styling attributes.
- in terms of actually binding the click event to activate the popup, and then providing means of submitting or discarding changes, there's actually a fair degree of complexity there which I don't feel like fully explaining here (would take a while). Take a look at the code, feel free to ask questions if you have any. In short: You have to attach a click event to every editable cell, which initializes the `input` text value with the cell content (`$input.val($cell.text());`), shows it (`$editor.css({'visibility':'visible'});`), and defines means of submitting or discarding (e.g. `$body.on('click.editable', function() { window.editableEnd(false); } );`). I've heavily used jQuery, which makes a lot of things a lot easier than they would be otherwise.
- I added some random bells and whistles for the heck of it, like radial background coloring on the cells with hover feedback (because you seem to want no borders, but I still wanted to get feedback on hovering), and selection coloring.

Comment: Thanks all for youre's effort to help me. Yes, i asked if it is possible, not to stackoverflow do my job instead of me. Thank again, now i know from where to start.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<tr><td id='tdcell1'> MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td> <td>MODIFY/EDIT/DELETE/NEW CONTENT</td></tr>
```

JS:

```
var x=document.getElementById("tdcell1");
alert(x.innerHTML);
```

This shows you how to access HTML content using JavaScript.
Explore it and learn how to edit contents.

To implement it very basically you can use `onClick` event and `prompt()` function.

The data would only remain until page is reloaded though. You need server-side data handler to store and load that information on next page load.

Hope it helps, it has to, StackOverflow is here to help, not to do your job for you.